# YouTube javascript not returning proper error codes (error 0 for everything)

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I can't seem to get my youtube javascript to give me the proper video error.  For example the following code should give me error code 150, but instead it gives me 0.

Embed Code on HTML

```
<object width='710' height='400' style='z-index: 1;'>
<param name='movie' value='https://www.youtube.com/v/Ze8bj80qL_I?version=3&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent'></param>
<param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'></param>
<param name='allowScriptAccess' value='always'></param>
<param name='wmode' value='transparent'></param>
<embed src='https://www.youtube.com/v/Ze8bj80qL_I?version=3&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' allowfullscreen='true' allowScriptAccess='always' width='710' height='400' id='myytplayer' wmode='transparent'></embed>
</object>
```

Javascript:

```
function onPlayerError(event) {
    alert(event);
}
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
    $(ytplayer).attr({
                 "src" : url.replace('?rel=0', '')+"?wmode=transparent",
                 "wmode" : "Opaque"
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but I can get the correct error code only if I use the [YouTube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) with the HTML5 player.

HTML:

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

function onPlayerError(event) {
    alert("Error code " + event.data);
}

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log("start");
    var player;
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        videoId: 'Ze8bj80qL_I',
        playerVars: {
            'autoplay': 1,
            'controls': 0,
            'html5': 1
        },
        events: {
            'onError': onPlayerError
        }
    });
}
```

The error code is **100**:

> The video requested was not found. This error occurs when a video has
>   been removed (for any reason) or has been marked as private.

[Here is the jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/9uyRB/2/) Tested in GC30.

Comment: Thanks, That seems to work, but now I'm getting different errors:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'rD' html5player-vflyIiNm2.js:910    and      Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://www.youtube.com/user_watch?noflv=1&html5=1&video_id=h9LiATNY0Ec&cpn…117%2C3300132%2C3300137%2C3300163%2C3310137%2C3310551%2C3310870&autoplay=1". html5player-vflyIiNm2.js:6

Comment: Also, my application dynamically loads new videos, so I need to be able to destroy and create players at will.  If I have my onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() function call a different function I get a "YT" undefined error, but everything works.